# Redirect UEFI Shell I/O

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I´d like to redirect the UEFI Shell stdin/stdout to work from a remote PC.
I have/see two options:

1) Via a UART/COM interface:
Is there any simple solution to get this run inside the shell? (I don´t want to enter the 'BIOS' settings but start redirection via shell script)

I´m able to write a UEFI-Shell application which uses the UART-Interface. And I found there is a Terminal driver at edk2\MdeModulePkg\Universal\Console\TerminalDxe. But I couldn´t find anything about how to use this to redirect the ConIn and ConOut.

2) Via SSH:The only information I found is that it is possible to set up a SSH server inside EFI Shell:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/why.html

But searching for more I couldn´t find any information about howor if there are already any UEFI apps/docs available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the TerminalDxe run.

It´s just compiling the TerminalDxe of EDK2

```
build -a X64 -p MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc -m MdeModulePkg/Universal/Console/TerminalDxe/TerminalDxe.inf
```

and then load it in the UEFI Shell

```
load TerminalDxe.efi
```